# How to "disable" the word-wrap in the legend text of chart made with antV library?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, graph-visualization, ant-design-pro, antv

So I am working on front-end and I am using [Ant design library](https://antv-g2plot.gitee.io/zh/examples/area/stacked/API) for stacked area charts. Everything else is working quite perfect so far but the text in legend is bit long so it is getting wrapped with [ellipsis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGKx2.png) by default. I have tried alot of options but nothing has worked so far. I want the legend to display all the text and disable word-wrap no matter how long the text is.
NOTE: This is my first ever question on stackoverflow so please feel free to ask for anything which I have missed to mention.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community.
For a better solution, you can attach your code snippet to your question.

Comment: If you don't have an official API, your only way is overriding `style` or checking in devtools the corresponding className and override it. There are a lot similar questions how its done in antd.

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks alot for the response. Yes, I have tried alot about overriding style but still it didn't work. :-\